# Access the contents of previous row

Tags: r

```
df=data.frame(Type=c('Sell','Buy','Sell','Buy'), 
              Date=c('2015-03-24','2014-12-04', '2014-11-07', '2014-05-22'), 
              Quantity=c(2000,600,50,500) ) 

Type        Date    Quantity  Volume
Sell    2015-03-24  2000      1400
Buy     2014-12-04  600       600
Sell    2014-05-22  500       0
Buy     2014-03-28  500       500
```

Hi, I want to generate values for Volume column based on the following logic

if Type is Sell then previous row [Volume] - current row [Quantity]

if Type is Buy then previous row [Volume] + current row [Quantity]

Comment: You might use [`lag`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lag.html).

Comment: How is `600 - 2000 = 1400`?

Comment: Starting from the oldest date i.e 2014-03-28 type is Buy and there is no previous row so it is 500. For 2014-05-22 Type is Sell , so current[Quantity]- previous row[Vol] = 500 -500 =0.

Comment: Look at the first row Volume, the previous Volume is 600 and sell 2000, shouldn't it be -1400?

Comment: Hi Psidom, scan from the bottom i.e. oldest date.

Comment: I am scaning from bottom. `500, 500 - 500 = 0, 0 + 600 = 600, 600 - 2000 = -1400`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df=data.frame(Type=c('Sell','Buy','Sell','Buy'), 
              Date=c('2015-03-24','2014-12-04', '2014-11-07', '2014-05-22'), 
              Quantity=c(2000,600,50,500) ) 
df

  Type       Date Quantity
1 Sell 2015-03-24     2000
2  Buy 2014-12-04      600
3 Sell 2014-11-07       50
4  Buy 2014-05-22      500

df$Volume <- df$Quantity[nrow(df)]
for (i in (nrow(df)-1):1) {
  if (df$Type[i] == 'Sell') {
    df$Volume[i] <- df$Volume[i+1] - df$Quantity[i]
  } else { # Buy
    df$Volume[i] <- df$Volume[i+1] + df$Quantity[i]
  }
}
df

  Type       Date Quantity Volume
1 Sell 2015-03-24     2000   -950
2  Buy 2014-12-04      600   1050
3 Sell 2014-11-07       50    450
4  Buy 2014-05-22      500    500
```

Maybe you'll want to order your data.frame first, just to be sure?

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. Was wondering there might be some short R style code to do the same ?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner Possibly. But I think good old programming techniques are easier for anyone to understand. And you're welcome.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner I misunderstood your question the first time. Is it right now?